# Zend Framework and string covertation using iconv

Tags: php, zend-framework, solaris, iconv, zend-validate

One site was moved to another server where is installed Solaris and other iconv settings. Now, when I validate anything with "StringLength" function from Zend Framework my scripts fail with this error:

```
Notice: iconv_strlen() [function.iconv-strlen]: Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to `UCS-4LE' is not allowed in /usr_files/phplibs/library/Zend/Validate/StringLength.php on line 213
```

As I understood, server does know about "UCS-4LE" and it is main problem.

Server administrator answered that he could resolve this problem. Do you have any ideas how I can setup ZF at this server?

Answer (score 1):

the iconv library was expecting a string encoded in 'UCS-4LE', but received one that it detected as 'UTF-8'. You probably have a different default encoding on the new server. Try passing the third parameter to the [constructor](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Validate/Zend_Validate_StringLength.html#sec-method-summary) (as `'utf-8'`).

Comment: I have tryied:

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

As well,

iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");


It doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Although an old topic, this one came up for me today while moving to a new server running xampp (Linux Suse, PHP 5.3.5, Zend Framework 1.11.10) . I reproduced the above error with the following test script:

```
<?php
echo iconv_strlen("hello");
?>
```

both on the command line and in browser. After some troubleshooting, I discovered that the following "solved" the immediate problem one of two ways:

```
<?php
echo iconv_strlen("hello", 'utf-8');
?>
```

or

```
<?php
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
echo iconv_strlen("hello");
?>
```

however adding the iconv_set_encoding in ZF did not work.

Changing php.ini to make the changes permanent did work for ZF

```
[iconv]
iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding = UTF-8
iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

However the original reason why iconv acts up on the new server is beyond me.